# Join routes origin and destination to rows with unique ID

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I'm trying to make a flight route map for some European airports in Tableau. I have the data in this formate:

[image: mydata]

and want to have it in pairs, for example as here:
[image: data I want]

I wanted to follow [this](https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2015/07/taking-path-function) tutorial but as I have a Mac version of Tableau Desktop "Legacy Connector" option is not available. 
I also found [this](https://blog.databender.net/2016/02/20/new-features-better-solutions/) link and was able to pivot the data but then in Tableau I still have origin and destination latitude and longitude. 
Is there any way to get the desired format of data in Tableau or Excel adding also unique path id column?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can do this using a UNION along with some calculated fields (and usually hiding some fields)

Comment: Is it possible that you help me out? I tried different thing during past days but simply cannot come to a solution as I'm quite new to Tableau. The link to the excel file is: [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-aPWeVSUl_xTjlJNEgyQndyc0E
Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I managed it, I needed to hide some fields. Then pivot the data, creating a calculated field with an ID for origin/departure and based on that crating a calculated field for the longitudes/latitudes.

Comment: glad to hear you got it working. Hope it was a good exercise. Why not write up your solution as an answer so others can learn from your steps? (its a frequent problem)